# UDP server to handle multiple clients

Tags: java, udp

I created a UDP server. Here's a skeleton

```
public class UDPserver {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
           while(true){
              .... some code ...
              packet = new DatagramPacket ( data , data.length, packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort() );
              .... some code ...
              socket.receive( ... );
           }
      }
}
```

Now, i want to make it handle multiple requests, so i checked out that  i have to implement Runnable.

```
public class UDPserver implements Runnable { }
```

I read that I also need to have a run(). But i don't understand run(). should i put the whole `while(true)` statement inside run()? what about main()? Can anyone show how to change my code above to handle multiple requests? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

move all the code inside the run method of UDPServer (including the while(true))

In your main method :

```
UDPServer udpServer = new UDPServer();
udpServer.start();
```

- To make sure that no excpetion won't break your main loop, remember to catch and handle all exceptions that might be rasied inside the while(true) loop

Answer (score 0):

You can also use new thread for each new connection for performing. For example:

```
 class PacketPerforming extends Thread {
 DatagramPacket pak; 
 PacketPerforming(DatagramPacket pak) {
  super();
  this.pak = pak;
 } 

 public void run() {
  // do somethoing with pak
 }

 }

 // in your server thread
 while (true) { // i prefered wirte for (;;)

  DatagramPacket pak; // take pak object form remote socket

  PacketPerforming perform = new PacketPerforming(pak);
  perform.start();

 }
```